# Turkish word filtering

Tags: python, strings, natural-language-processing

I need to filter Turkish words according to vovel alternation rules. For example -ler is plural but can have form of -lar thus I use metaphonemes for these transitive allomorphs as vovel_dict in my algorithm.

There is only one condition not to alternate vovel it's 'ken' which excluded. I wrote this but it takes too much runtime do you have any suggestions?

```
def char_filter(morph):
    char_dict = {'d': 'D', 't': 'D', 'a': 'A', 'e': 'A', 'ı': 'H', 'i': 'H', 'u': 'H', 'C': 'C', 'g': 'G', 'k': 'G'}
    res = []
    res1 = []
    flag = []

    if 'ken' in morph:
        flag.append([morph.rindex('ken'), ['k','e','n']])

    for i in morph:
        res2 = i
        if i in char_dict:
            res2 = i.upper()
        res1.append(res2)

    if len(flag) > 0:
        for z in flag:
            res1[z[0]:z[0]+3] = z[1]
    res.append(string.join(res1, sep=''))
    return res[0]
```

Answer (score 7):

## Naming

`res`, `res1`, `res2`? These names convey absolutely no meaning. `flag`? Sounds like some sort of boolean value to me; but you assign it a list. `i`, `z`? one-letter variable names are essentially used for integer indices, not characters or… what is `z` already… oh, a list.

Even `morph` sounds badly chosen, I’m laking a bit of context here to fully understand it, I guess, but I would have used `origin_string` or something alike.

## Control flow

```
if len(flag) > 0:
    for z in flag:
        # do something
```

is twice as much complicate than it should be. Once because `if len(flag) > 0` can be written `if flag`: empty container are considered `False` in a boolean context. And once again because the `if` is not needed: `for z in flag` will be a no-op if `flag` is an empty container.

Also, since you’re not modifying `morph` and the only thing you store in `flag` (if any) is `[morph.rindex('ken'), ['k','e','n']]`, why not get rid of `flag` and directly use that list in the last part of your computation?

```
def char_filter(morph):
    char_dict = {'d': 'D', 't': 'D', 'a': 'A', 'e': 'A', 'ı': 'H', 'i': 'H', 'u': 'H', 'C': 'C', 'g': 'G', 'k': 'G'}
    res = []
    res1 = []

    for i in morph:
        res2 = i
        if i in char_dict:
            res2 = i.upper()
        res1.append(res2)

    if 'ken' in morph:
        i = morph.rindex('ken')
        res1[i:i+3] = ['k','e','n']
    res.append(string.join(res1, sep=''))
    return res[0]
```

## Data structures

Most of the data structures you use are not suited to your needs. Why storing only one string as the first item of `res` if you extract it right after having assigned it. Store the string directly in `res` intead of `res[0]`. Better: do not use `res` and return the string right after building it, you’re not making any other use of `res` anyway:

```
return ''.join(res1)
```

Also note the prefered syntax for `join` which is an operator of the separator string.

You’re also building a dictionary in `char_dict` but never using the values stored into it, only checking for the existence of keys. Two possibilities:

- either you have a bug and need to use `res2 = char_dict[i]` instead of `res2 = i.upper()`;
- or you just need to simplify the data structure and only store the characters that you want to test against. A list, a string or a set are better fit for this task.

I will consider the second option.

The last thing to note is that this collection will not be changed between calls so we can safely define it outside of the function to avoid building a new one each time we call `char_filter`.

## A little bit on pythonic constructs

```
some_list = []
for variable in some_collection:
    value = some_function(variable)
    some_list.append(value)
```

Is better written with a [list-comprehension](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions): more readable and faster.

```
some_list = [some_function(variable) for variable in some_collection]
```

## Proposed improvements

```
SPECIAL_CHARS = 'dtaeıiuCgk'

def char_filter(origin_string):
    filtered_letters = [char.upper() if char in SPECIAL_CHARS else char
                        for char in origin_string]

    if 'ken' in origin_string:
        i = origin_string.rindex('ken')
        filtered_letters[i:i+3] = ['k','e','n']

    return ''.join(filtered_letters)
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposal,
I already did some improvements on i.upper() as you suggested. I'm gonna implement your proposed improvement and share the runtime difference in 3 days because a 10000 iteration on huge data still processing and this is a small and most slow part of it.

Comment: I think in this case `dict` is better then `str`, as `SPECIAL_CHARS`'s data type. Where `set` is the best. As `set` and `dict` both have \$O(1)\$ lookup, where `str` has \$O(n)\$. Thanks to Python's [TimeComplexity](https://wiki.python.org/moin/TimeComplexity) page.

Comment: @JoeWallis Agreed. `frozenset` are best but string is not so bad. Better than list of characters (for character lookups). On my mind `dict`s are not right for this purpose since they store additional data that are unneeded here. Anyway, I mentionned `set` in the post but used a string in the final code excerpt for readability.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger I forgot about `frozenset`, silly me. In this case the data type doesn't really matter, but what's so bad about a list? To me both `list` and `str` are as bad, is it just strings internal immutability? Also `set('dtaeıiuCgk')` and `frozenset('dtaeıiuCgk')` are both readable...

Comment: @JoeWallis I think that's because strings are only made of chatacters and lists might contain any types. I'll try to find back the source of my claim, if possible.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18139681/5069029

Comment: @MathiasEttinger That's a nice link, I definitely didn't know about the 'BMHBNFS' search. I'll remove this comment tomorrow.

Answer (score 0):

I compared two codes actually I expected @MathiasEttinger's proposal to be faster(it looks beatiful) but when I run test script several times. I see my bad looking codes are faster do you have any idea why ? Below both functions, test loops and results:

```
def char_filter(morph):
char_dict = {'d': 'D', 't': 'D', 'a': 'A', 'e': 'A', 'ı': 'H', 'i': 'H', 'u': 'H', 'C': 'C', 'g': 'G', 'k': 'G'}
res = []
res1 = []
flag = []

if 'ken' in morph:
    flag.append([morph.rindex('ken'), ['k','e','n']])

for i in morph:
    res2 = i
    if i in char_dict:
        res2 = char_dict[i]
    res1.append(res2)

if len(flag) > 0:
    for z in flag:
        res1[z[0]:z[0]+3] = z[1]
res.append(string.join(res1, sep=''))
return res[0]
```

This is right version what is proposed

```
def char_filter1(origin_string):
char_dict = {'d': 'D', 't': 'D', 'a': 'A', 'e': 'A', 'ı': 'H', 'i': 'H', 'u': 'H', 'C': 'C', 'g': 'G', 'k': 'G'}
filtered_letters = [char_dict[char] if char in char_dict.keys() else char
                    for char in origin_string]

if 'ken' in origin_string:
    i = origin_string.rindex('ken')
    filtered_letters[i:i+3] = ['k','e','n']

return ''.join(filtered_letters)
```

Test Function

```
measure=0
start_time1 = time.time()
for i in range(500000):
    a=char_filter1('gidiyolarkendegeliyor')
print a
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time1))
measure += (time.time() - start_time1)
print measure/500000
measure=0

start_time = time.time()

for i in range(500000):
    a=char_filter('gidiyolarkendegeliyor')
print a
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
measure += (time.time() - start_time)
print measure/500000
```

And resulted as:

--char_filter1- 8.44659018517 seconds ---

1.68932442665e-05

--char_filter- 6.04725313187 seconds ---

1.20945320129e-05

Comment: I’m a bit late on this one, but you’re basically adding useless work by calling `char_dict.keys()` for the lookup. You can call `char_dict.get(char, char)` to achieve the same functionality than your ternary operator. Lastly, move the definition of `char_dict` outside of the function, it will save time too.